# Why is Jetty needed when the Solr stack already comes with Apache?

Tags: solr, jetty

Disclaimer: I am absolutely clueless about the Java world of things, other than knowing that Java code runs on a Java VM.  I have a Solr instance running, and it uses Jetty.  What I don't understand: why is there a need for Jetty when there is Apache web server running and sending requests to Solr at port # 8983?

I know this may be a silly question (that I am missing some part of the overall picture), and will appreciate your hand-holding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache httpd](http://httpd.apache.org/) is a very good web server than can be used for handling http requests, serving static files, and so forth. [Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty/) (or [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), another choice) are servlet containers, which are used as the environment in which a web application -- often a Java program -- runs.

It's very common to have an instance of Apache httpd running, handling certain requests, and forwarding other requests to a servlet container.

In this case, SOLR is a web application, and is using Jetty as its servlet container.

Comment: So Jetty provides the Java VM in which Solr runs?

Comment: Yes, exactly, among other services it provides for the web application.

Comment: And servlets are small Java codes?  I did look up servlet on Wikipedia, but did not get a clear picture.  (I am from the .NET world.)

Comment: A servlet is a web application standard. It would be comparable to an asp.net app.